# How to save selected list in Laravel using One to Many Relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm thinking how can I save a user selected list in my table **users**? If the user select the first option the values will be inserted in my `role_id` with a value of 1 and so on.

```
<div class = "form-group {{ $errors->has('role') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">

<label for = "role" class = "control-label">Role</label>

<select class = "form-control" name = "role">

    <option selected disabled>Please select role</option>
    <option value = "role1">Supplies Officer</option>
    <option value = "role2">Admin Officer</option>
    <option value = "role3">Attorney</option>
    <option value = "role4">Chairman</option>

</select>

 @if ($errors->has('role'))
    <span class = "help-block">{{ $errors->first('role') }}</span>
 @endif
```

Sample SQL:

```
INSERT INTO `users`(`role_id`, `email`, `username`) VALUES (1,'francis@gmail.com','francis')
```

I have a table **roles** has a one to many relationship with **users** table.

[image]

**roles** Table: I already inserted a values here.

[image: roles Table]

User(Model)

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
use Authenticatable;

protected $table = 'users';

protected $fillable = [
    'username',
    'email',
    'password',
    'role_id',
];

public function role()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Role');
}
}
```

Role(Model):

```
class Role extends Model
{
protected $table = 'roles';

public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany('User');
}
}
```

Controller:

I still don't have any idea here how can I insert or save the selected list. Any help would appreciated!

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
                            //This will be unique in users table
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|email|max:255',
        'username' => 'required|unique:users|alpha|max:20',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'role' => 'required',
    ]);

    $email = $request['email'];
    $username = $request['username'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
    $role = $request['role'];

    $user = new User();
    $user->email = $email; //Accessing properties of Model
    $user->username = $username;
    $user->password = $password;


    $user->save();

}
```

Comment: Why doesn't `$user->role_id = $role` work for you?  I think you're overthinking the relationship.

Comment: @Devon I tried that but it says. Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`onlinesystem`.`users`, CONSTRAINT `users_role_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `roles` (`id`)

Comment: Because your form value is `role1` not `1`..  Either strip the characters or change the values.

Comment: @Devon hey bro this works.  I see my error that's why it's not inserting the values because the `role_id` has a data type of `INT` my bad. Btw your too fast.

Answer (score 0):

You passed your role_id into the User object.

```
$user->role_id = 1;
$user->save();
```

Now your role is assigned to your user. You can check your SQL database or make a dd() on the $user variable.

```
dd($user);
```

You can assign it with eloquent, which is a better approach.

```
$role = \Role::findOrFail($request['role_id']);
$role->user()->assign($user)->push(); // This ligne assign the id of the Role Model into the User Model automaticly.
```

In this case Role model must have a belongsTo relationship on User model.